# Losing data from arraylist

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, arraylist

I am having a problem in which I am losing data in an arrayList.  After I call the method Refresh in class MPUComp I go into the class mpuChecker and call updateTextArea.

By doing this I am losing the data that existed in the arraylist in MPUComp.  What I am doing wrong.  I think it has to do with how I call the class.  How do I correctly keep this data?

```
public class MPUComp extends JFrame {
{

private mpuChecker mC;
public ArrayList<String> oldTags = new ArrayList<String>();

public void menu()
{
//...
class MenuActionListener3 implements ActionListener {   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        mC = new mpuChecker();
        mC.CheckMpu(path, textField.getText(),1);
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
class MenuActionListener4 implements ActionListener {   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        mC = new mpuChecker();
        mC.CheckMpu(path2, textField_1.getText(),2);
        setVisible(false);
    }
}   

public void refresh(String pane1) {
    textArea_1.append(pane1 + "\n");
    System.out.println(getOldTags().size());
    System.out.println(oldTags.size());
    //both print out zero when called second
}


public void updateTextArea(final String text) {
       textArea_2.append(text + "\n");
       oldTags.add(text);
       System.out.println(oldTags.size());
       //prints out the correct arraylist size
}
}
}

//second class which calls updateTextArea and refresh

public class mpuChecker {

   private MPUComp mC = new MPUComp();

public void CheckMpu(String path, String searchToken, int form)
{
 // Print the text to the appropriate text-area either 1 or 2
public void ary1(int path)
{   
    if(path == 1)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l <  midTags.size(); l++)
    {
        mC.refresh(midTags.get(l));
    }
    }
    if(path == 2)
    {
        for(int lk = 0; lk <  midTags2.size(); lk++)
    {
        mC.updateTextArea(midTags2.get(lk));
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thats not important I deleted it I was trying to use getters/setters

Comment: there's a bunch of undefined variables in this code, for example midTags in checkmpu(..); could you add detail on what those are? I don't really understand your code this way; the same goes for method-calls for which you didn't print the corresponding methods.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on what jpm suggested, to avoid this you could do

```
private MPUChecker mC = new MPUChecker();
```

in MPUComp. That way you only instantiate that mpuchecker once. Both ActionListeners could then use that MPUChecker.

If you want each ActionListener to have its own MPUChecker, you could move the creation of their listeners into the body of those internal classes, like so

```
class MenuActionListener3 implements ActionListener {   
    MPUChecker menu3mC = new mpuChecker();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        menu3mC.CheckMpu(path, textField.getText(),1);
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, MPUChecker itself might be referring to the wrong MPUComp, since you create one for the MPUChecker at initialisation of that object. Unless that is the intended behavior, you could remove

```
private MPUComp mC = new MPUComp();
```

from MPUChecker, make CheckMPU static and give it an additional parameter: the MPUComp it's supposed to check.

Comment: private static MPUComp mC = new MPUComp();  in mpuchecker class  fixed my problem thank you!!  I am not exactly sure why though.

Comment: @G.Bach Thanks for expounding on my answer. You have my upvote.

Comment: @CharlieMorrison: the reason this works is that now, MPUComp mc is only instantiated once, at the time the program is started, so now all calls of CheckMPU(..) refer to the same object.

Comment: @jpm: thank you, I probably wouldn't have spotted that, so an upvote for you as well!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like every time one of your action listeners is triggered, it creates a new `mpuChecker`, and each one of these creates it's own `MPUComp` (which is unrelated to the original). It is these unrelated `MPUComp`s on which `refresh` and `updateTextArea` are being called, not the `MPUComp` this all started from. As such, these new `MPUComp`s won't have access to any of the data in the original (including the contents of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: how can I fix it.  I thought that might be a problem but I am not sure where to do a mC = new mpuChecker();  so that both action listeners can have access

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obvious in your code that could be causing it, so I'm just going to suggest some general tips.

The first thing that comes to mind is that somewhere you are reassigning oldTags.  Look through your code to see if you are setting oldTags somewhere.  I noticed that you have it as a public variable.  Do you have a reason for that?  You should always make variables private unless there is a good reason for them to be public.

After that start looking for method calls that remove elements from ArrayLists (clear, remove, set).